# iOS app. Looking for Weeks picker!

Tags: search, ios, filter, datetimepicker

I'm working on iOS app for medical doctors that lets them find a job.

Doctors work part time and could change several hospitals for a year. Hospitals hire them when they need a specific practitioner. Doctors decide what period they want to work.

To start searching for jobs doctor has to provide his/her availability (in week numbers, it's common for them at the moment).

**For example, doctor could say s/he's available for work through weeks 10-15 and, also, on weeks 17, 21.**

The major requirements:

- user can pick the weeks range or a single week number
- there is an option to have ranges and single numbers at the same time
- the large part of the audience is senior people 55+ so I would like to stay away from patterns and gestures for 'power users'

I struggle to find the solution for this.  Do you have any ideas of how it could be designed?

I will appreciate any ideas, insights or suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quick clarification: you mentioned in the title that it's a date and time picker, but the description only mentions a week picker. Could you clarify which features you need, and an example?

In the meantime, here's a quick example of a week picker, which might be easier for older audiences to use, for a couple reasons:

- It is visually similar to a paper calendar (less mental effort)
- It has plenty of labels and other visual markers to make it easier to find the dates they need
- Simple interface and instructions make it so users don't need to learn something new: tapping selects or deselects the week

[image: No week selected]
[image: Weeks selected]

Comment: Thank you for the Weeks picker example. It's very interesting! Definitely worth considering.  <br/>

"Quick clarification: you mentioned in the title that it's a date and time picker, but the description only mentions a week picker. Could you clarify which features you need, and an example?"  <br/>

I need week picker. I mentioned Date picker in the title just to make it easier to understand since I guess, weeks pickers are pretty rare (at least, I've never met one for 10 years in UX:)

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth considering the issues of displaying availability.

Socially we live in time (year, month, week, day, hour, minute, second)

You mentioned that you are only interested in **weeks** 
1 - 2 - 3 week in a year (Monday-Friday) - what about weekends?

If You automate smaller values, the user can only choose the week of availability (days, hours, minutes, seconds - automatically in the constructor)

But it is also necessary to specify the **hours** (unless automatically assigned).

---

The situation You describes operate on ranges (start,end)

**Natively**:  designing 2 inputs - **Start** - **End** with characteristically design pattern (based on this data, system with easing can compute what You need):

[image]

or:

[image]

And you consider time zones?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The use case is specific to this audience. They think in week's numbers, I mean they know they are free on weeks 15, 17, 22, etc of 2020 and want to find the job for this period. It's important to provide reference in 'human' language like mentioning that, for example, week 15 starts on Apr 6 but the input itself should be in weeks otherwise they'll have to Google dates for corresponding weeks.

The time they are available to work is another filter. Here, we just think about weeks range.

Comment: The challenge is to design control that allows to input multiple week ranges or single weeks for the search request (like 10-15, 17, 23). That's why just Start End inputs do not solve the whole problem.

Now, I consider the plain input field would be the most flexible solution. But it's not 'error-proof' that's why I'm looking for another pattern.

Week is not Mon-Fri, it's Mon-Sun.

Comment: Ok, so You can render a lot of circles (and categorize for month) - every circle represent one week - in rules of checkboxes. Also implement a slider between months/quarters.